# Relativistic Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, relativity

The question stated: By what percentage does your rest mass increase when you climb 30m to the top of a ten-story building?

New to the concept of relativistic energy, I was a bit confused with figuring out how to approach this question.

The relativistic energy of a particle (its normal total energy but incorporating relativity effects due to its high speeds) is equal to:

$E= K+mc^2=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}=\gamma m c^2 $

Since the equation is only the sum of the particles kinetic energy and rest mass, I am uncertain in how to find the rest mass increase knowing only the change in height (potential energy increase). Since I am not moving at relativistic speeds I can just use the normal conservation of energy formula:

$E_{initial}=E_{final} $

(assuming I started at height h=0m, and all energy was conserved while climbing)

$\frac{1}{2} m v^2 = mgh $

which when simplified and rearranged for speed v equals to:

$v=\sqrt{2gh}$

The formula for relativistic mass is:

$m_{rel}=\frac{m_{rest}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

Since the question asked me "by what *percentage* does your rest mass increase", I am assuming I have to find:

$\frac{m_{rel}}{m_{rest}} \times 100$

Rearranging the formula for relativistic mass and substituting in the equation for speed v from above:

$\frac{m_{rel}}{m_{rest}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2gh}{c^2}}}
$

However this gives me an answer of 1, which is clearly incorrect. The answer stated in the text is $3.3 \times 10^{-13}  $ %.

I have checked over my work, but I don't know whether I have made an error in my reasoning or my calculations. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a poor question because your rest mass does not increase when you climb 30m. However I can see how the examiner expects you to answer.

If your mass is *m* then your energy when static at the bottom of the building is $mc^2$. To climb a distance h you have to hav work $mgh$ done on you, so your energy is now $mc^2 + mgh$. So the percentage change in your energy is:

$$ \%E = \frac{mgh}{mc^2} = \frac{gh}{c^2} $$

and if you set $h = 30$m you find this comes to $3.27 \times 10^{-15}$ or $3.27 \times 10^{-13}$%.

But let me emphasise that to say your mass has increased when you climb is meaningless nonsense. If you take a bound system (e.g. you and the Earth) and add some energy $E$ to it then it's true that the *mass of the bound system* will increase by $E/c^2$. For example this is the origin of the [notorious mass deficit in nuclei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Mass_defect). However to claim that the rest mass of any particular part of the bound system changes is meaningless.

Comment: It's bad enough that "mass" can mean different things in relativity, and now we have people explicitly saying "rest mass" when they mean the exact opposite!

Comment: There is a nice Wikipedia article on mass in general relatvity:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_general_relativity . What John has described is known as the Newtonian limit for the mass.

Answer (score 5):

I believe John's answer is sufficient to guide you through the question. My answer will try to pinpoint your mistake in your working. Your working is mostly correct except the ratio $\frac{m_{rel}}{m_{rest}}$.

To get the correct value for $\frac{m_{rel}}{m_{rest}}$, use Taylor expansion:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2gh}{c^2}}} = (1-\frac{2gh}{c^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 1 + (-\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{2gh}{c^2}) + \ldots$

Terms with power higher than 1 is omitted since they are very small compared to the first and second term. The *increase* in mass is the second term, which you can verify is $3.27\times10^{-15}$. The reason you get 1 is because the number differs from 1 by such a small quantity (after 15 figures) that a scientific or graphical calculator cannot display.